# Dynamic List of Available Custom Material Themes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm messing with custom themes for Angular Material (using Angular v5.x). I can create my themes, and change from one theme to another (it's clunky, but it works), but I can't figure out how to get a dynamic list of available themes.

So instead of hard-coding a list of theme names/classes somewhere (to be populated into a dropdown), I want to be able to pull a dynamic list of however many custom themes have been included in the app, and put THOSE in a drop-down menu.

So if I have something along these lines in my `style.scss` file:

```scss
.my-light-theme {
@include angular-material-theme($my-light-theme);
}
.my-dark-theme {
@include angular-material-theme($my-dark-theme);
}
.my-blue-theme {
@include angular-material-theme($my-blue-theme);
}
.my-green-theme {
@include angular-material-theme($my-green-theme);
}
...
```

How can I dynamically scrape that list later in my app?